# two datatable adding

Tags: c#, windows

I have two datatables.

1st table----->  `DataTable _dtMain = new COrder().GetDetails();`
2nd table----->  `DataTable _dtSub  =  new CGrid().GetSubDetails();`

I want to add the above two tables.  I am using `_dtMain.Merge(_dtSub );`
But it will append `_dtSub` table to `_dtMain` table.  I want datatable to add second table to first table in column wise (that means after first table last column)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a lot of research , i find out the answer for my question that i posted before. Here is the code for combing 2 datatable & the data inside it.

```
   public DataTable CombineTable(DataTable _dtGridDetails, DataTable _dtSubGridDetails)
   {
       //first create the datatable columns 
       DataSet mydataSet = new DataSet();
       mydataSet.Tables.Add("  ");
       DataTable myDataTable = mydataSet.Tables[0];

       //add left table columns 
       DataColumn[] dcLeftTableColumns = new DataColumn[_dtGridDetails.Columns.Count];
       _dtGridDetails.Columns.CopyTo(dcLeftTableColumns, 0);

       foreach (DataColumn LeftTableColumn in dcLeftTableColumns)
       {
           if (!myDataTable.Columns.Contains(LeftTableColumn.ToString()))
               myDataTable.Columns.Add(LeftTableColumn.ToString());
       }

       //now add right table columns 
       DataColumn[] dcRightTableColumns = new DataColumn[_dtSubGridDetails.Columns.Count];
       _dtSubGridDetails.Columns.CopyTo(dcRightTableColumns, 0);

       foreach (DataColumn RightTableColumn in dcRightTableColumns)
       {
           if (!myDataTable.Columns.Contains(RightTableColumn.ToString()))
           {
              // if (RightTableColumn.ToString() != RightPrimaryColumn)
                   myDataTable.Columns.Add(RightTableColumn.ToString());
           }
       }

       //add left-table data to mytable 
       foreach (DataRow LeftTableDataRows in _dtGridDetails.Rows)
       {
           myDataTable.ImportRow(LeftTableDataRows);               
       }

       for (int nIndex = 0; nIndex <= myDataTable.Rows.Count-1; nIndex++)
       {
           if (nIndex == _dtSubGridDetails.Rows.Count)
               break;
           myDataTable.Rows[nIndex][columnindex] = _dtSubGridDetails.Rows[nIndex][columnindex];           
       } 
       return myDataTable;
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't think there any built-in method for the thing you want to achieve.

I think you need to make your own implementation for that stuff, like for example an extension method

```
public static DataTable Aggregate(this DataTable dt1, DataTable dt2)
{
    var aggregator = new DataTable(); 
    //add columns from dt1 and dt2 

    //add rows from dt1 dt2
}
```

or, you can do a complete `Outer Join` on both tables, like descrived in [this](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/37444/Full-Outer-Join-of-Two-DataTables-C-Code) article.